# createUserWithEmailAndPassword.then() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was using Firebase to the register part of my project. Yesterday it was working fine, but now, the `.then()` of the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` stop working and I don't understand why.

My code is very simple:

```
import React from "react";

import { auth } from "../../firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

class Register extends React.Component{

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "mail@mail.com", "password")
        .then((userCredential)=>{
            console.log(userCredential)
        })
    }

    render(){
                return(
                    <div className="add-form-container">
                        <h1 className="title">Registrarse</h1>
                        <span className="form-container">
                            <span className="input-add">
                                <p className="p-input">Usuario</p>
                                <input className="input-" id="input-user" type="text" />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <span className="input-add">
                                <p className="p-input">Correo electrónico</p>
                                <input className="input-" id="input-mail" type="email" />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <span className="input-add">
                                <p className="p-input">Contraseña</p>
                                <input className="input-" id="input-pass" type="password" />
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <button className="add-button" onClick={this.onSubmit} id="post-button">Crear</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

export default  Register;
```

Basically it return a `console.log` after create the user. The user is successfully created, but the `console.log` never shows. I changed it for `alert()` or another callback, but anything works.

Any solutions?

(I'm using only React and JavaScript)

Comment: Just to clarify, do you create a user with the same email and password every time? Are you sure it works, and that you don't actually get an error when you add the same user multiple times? Try adding a catch block to see if there are any errors

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that a user with the email address already exists, but to know for certain what's going wrong you should implement `catch` in addition to `then`:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "mail@mail.com", "password")
.then((userCredential)=>{
    console.log(userCredential)
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case my comment was actually the answer, I'll add it as an answer as well. Try adding a catch block to see if there are any errors when you try creating a new user:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "mail@mail.com", "password")
  .then((userCredential)=>{
    console.log(userCredential)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log({err}))
```